# Partial helper doesn't render partials in .hbs file

Tags: assemble

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  In working with v0.6.0, the Readme indicates you can use:

```
{%= partial("partial-name") %}
```

However, these are just getting printed as plain text.  Do I need to use a different engine if I want to have those tags parsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assemble allows using different engines and the example that you have is using lodash with custom delimiters.

To use the default partials helper in handlebars do `{{partial "partial-name"}}`

Comment: Oh my.  I'm positive I had tried that and I kept getting an error.  Of course - it works.  Thanks for the help and all the work you guys are putting into Assemble!